# Blazor Component Inheriting base component with type parameters does not render

Tags: generics, inheritance, types, blazor

Been running into a Blazor issue where I'm trying to set-up a base component with dynamic typing where the derived class specifies the types.

Check out the following example on the telerik Blazor REPL:

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wdEyaKFd05ydoBZ122

Code Snippets:

TableComponent.razor

```
@namespace BlazorRepl.UserComponents

@inherits TableComponentBase<TItem>

@typeparam TItem

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var str in Headers())
                {
                    <th>@str</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in items)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var str in Rows(item))
                    {
                        <td>@str.ToString()</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

TableComponent.cs

```
namespace BlazorRepl.UserComponents
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

    public class TableComponentBase<TItem> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<TItem> items { get; set; }

        protected virtual List<TItem> Rows(TItem item) { return new List<TItem>() { }; }
        protected virtual List<string> Headers() { return new List<string>() { "Placeholder" }; }
    }
}
```

ZoomCampaign.cs

```
namespace BlazorRepl.UserComponents
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ZoomCampaign : TableComponentBase<string>
    {
        protected override List<string> Headers()
        {
            return new List<string>() { "#", "Name" };
        }
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@using BlazorRepl.UserComponents

<ZoomCampaign items=@(new List<string> {"test"})/>
```

This compiles fine, yet nothing is rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Not sure what to try for this to be honest!

Comment: Ask yourself - what should it render? ZoomCampaign doesn't include any markup or BuildRenderTree, nor does TableComponentBase

Comment: TableComponent does have mark-up found in TableComponent.razor. And as for 'what should it render?' I expected it to render what was inherited!

Comment: You haven't shared any markup for `TableComponent` - you have for `TableComponents` which inherits the class defined in TableComponent.cs, but ZoomCampaign also inherits `TableComponentBase<T>` - please make your question accurate and complete. Does ZoomCampaign also have it's own razor file?  These are crucail pieces of information for this question.

Comment: Corrected the obvious typo. So, I think that's the bit I was getting wrong, I was inheriting from Base instead of the component directly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

If you want to create an answer for that, go ahead :)

Comment: You still have `class TableComponentBase` in file `TableComponent.cs`.  `TableComponent.razor` is not part of  `<ZoomCampaign>`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying ZoomCampaign inheriting from TableComponentBase directly was the root-cause.

Answer (score -1):

## You need to separate the ForEach Statement iterations and the components it renders.

### Then give the component the data that it uses in the rendering of the component.

### So instead of this...

```
@foreach (var str in Headers())
{
     <th>@str</th>
}
```

### Render the component in the ForEach statement and have the logic in the component.

```
@foreach (var product in ProductsInCartOverview)
{
    <Cart Product="product" />
}
```

### Then have the logic in the component.

```
<th>@str</th>
```